# Cross Validation Score

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I am a beginner in machine learning and we are learning cross-validation. I was using the manual but random split of 50-50 on a 1000 observation data. What I got back was an error rate of 0.98. Does that mean that my model fails to detect future prediction 98% of the time?

Comment: More details about your exact output would help, but it does sound like you get the right class $2\%$ of the time and the wrong class $98\%$ of the time. (This kind of poor performance is not unusual for a first go at a problem.)

Comment: 2% of the time and the wrong class 98% of the time.